# Telnet to EC2 from another EC2 hosting robot framework scripts

Tags: amazon-ec2, robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

**BACKGROUND**:

We have many data services(DS) installed in different AWS EC2s. We are automating test cases for each of these using Robot Framework.
We will be executing the test scripts from a specific EC2 instance where we have a tool setup.
I have my robot script inside this specific EC2 and I need to 1st establish connection to my EC2 instances where one of the service is hosted.

**ISSUE**

I tried `telnet` and `SSH` but unlike `telnet <IP add> <port>` , here username is mandatory. I passed ec2-user and root, but it throws me authentication error. Can anyone guide me how to successfully establish connection between 2 EC2 instances so that I can run my test scripts successfully ?

```
Documentation      Robot Framework test script
Library            Telnet
*** Variables ***
${host}            10.231.XX.XX
${port}            11211
${username}        ec2-user
${password}        ${EMPTY}
*** Test Cases ***
Test Telnet
     Open Connection     ${host}
     Login               ${username}     ${password}     delay=1
     Execute Command     hostname
     Close All Connections
```

Comment: start by verifying that telnet with given credentials work when connecting manually from that particular host to the host it needs to connect to..

Comment: [root@ip-10-231-XX-XX[gtndealpq-mcd-1-op-test] ec2-user]# telnet 10.231.XX.XX 11211 -l ec2-user
Trying 10.231.XX.XX...
Connected to 10.231.XX.XX. It works fine with telnet and username.